# How do I prove that one term is greater than the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm supposed to prove that
$$
a^2+b^2 > \dfrac{1}{2}a^2+ab+\dfrac{1}{2}b^2
$$

Comment: Does $1/2a^2$ mean $\frac{1}{2}a^2$ or $\frac{1}{2a^2}$?

Comment: Multiply by $2$ then put everything to the right then you got $$ (a - b)^2 > 0$$ as long as $a\neq b$.

Comment: are you assuming $a\neq b$?

Comment: They are **expressions**, not *equations*.

Comment: Note that this way to write $1/2a^2+ab+1/2b^2$ for$ \frac1{2}a^2+ab+\frac1{2}b^2$ is very confusing and ambiguos. In short is better use $a^2/2+ab+b^2/2$.

Comment: one half $a^2$ and $b^2$, sorry im not familar with how things work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT...consider multiplying out $\frac 12(a-b)^2$